# Python Enum and Pydantic : accept enum member's composition

Tags: python, enums, metaprogramming, pydantic

I have an enum :

```py
from enum import Enum

class MyEnum(Enum):
    val1 = "val1"
    val2 = "val2"
    val3 = "val3"
```

I would like to validate a pydantic field based on that enum.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    my_enum_field: MyEnum
```

BUT I would like this validation to also accept string that are composed by the Enum members.

So for example : "val1_val2_val3" or "val1_val3" are valid input.

I cannot make this field as a string field with a validator since I use a test library ([hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [pydantic-factories](https://github.com/Goldziher/pydantic-factories)) that needs this type in order to render one of the values from the enum (for mocking random inputs)

So this :

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    my_enum_field: str

    @validator('my_enum_field', pre=True)
    def validate_my_enum_field(cls, value):
        split_val = str(value).split('_')
        if not all(v in MyEnum._value2member_map_ for v in split_val):
            raise ValueError()
        return value
```

Could work, but break my test suites because the field is anymore of enum types.

How to keep this field as an Enum type (to make my mock structures still valid) and make pydantic accept composite values in the same time ?

So far, I tried to dynamically extend the enum, with no success.

Comment: How many variations are valid? A more pragmatic solution could just be to add each one individually to the enum class. Code complexity has a real cost. Sometimes the "dumb" solution can suffice quite nicely.

Comment: Thanks @flakes, but this enum has more than 30 members in reality, and the variations could be any combinations of any numbers of members..., so this is obviously not a solution

Comment: Would it be possible to replace the structure with a list? `my_enum_field: Union[MyEnum, list[MyEnum]]` Then you don't have to do the `_` splitting and a single value is still valid

Comment: Well this is a good idea ! I am working on that now. Thanks

Comment: The `_` will always be there since it is the client that sending this input (and I cannot change it). But with you idea I am trying to store the input as a list...will let you know

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looked at this a bit further, and I believe something like this could be helpful. You can create a new class to define the property that is a list of enum values.

This class can supply a customized `validate` method and supply a `__modify_schema__` to keep the information present about being a string in the json schema.

We can define a base class for generic lists of concatenated enums like this:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Type
from enum import Enum

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Enum)


class ConcatenatedEnum(Generic[T], list[T]):
    enum_type: Type[T]

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, value: str):
        return list(map(cls.enum_type, value.split("_")))

    @classmethod
    def __modify_schema__(cls, field_schema: dict):
        all_values = ', '.join(f"'{ex.value}'" for ex in cls.enum_type)
        field_schema.update(
            title=f"Concatenation of {cls.enum_type.__name__} values",
            description=f"Underscore delimited list of values {all_values}",
            type="string",
        )
        if "items" in field_schema:
            del field_schema["items"]
```

In the `__modify_schema__` method I also provide a way to generate a description of which values are valid.

To use this in your application:

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
    val1 = "val1"
    val2 = "val2"
    val3 = "val3"


class MyEnumList(ConcatenatedEnum[MyEnum]):
    enum_type = MyEnum


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    my_enum_field: MyEnumList
```

Examples Models:

```
print(MyModel.parse_obj({"my_enum_field": "val1"}))
print(MyModel.parse_obj({"my_enum_field": "val1_val2"}))
```

```
my_enum_field=[<MyEnum.val1: 'val1'>]
my_enum_field=[<MyEnum.val1: 'val1'>, <MyEnum.val2: 'val2'>]
```

Example Schema:

```
print(json.dumps(MyModel.schema(), indent=2))
```

```
{
  "title": "MyModel",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "my_enum_field": {
      "title": "Concatenation of MyEnum values",
      "description": "Underscore delimited list of values 'val1', 'val2', 'val3'",
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "my_enum_field"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What you suggested in the Question's comments was enough in my case (marking the type as a union of the enum and a list of it) But thank you for this second advanced suggestion. Will try too !

Comment: I don't understand `if "items" in field_schema: del field_schema["items"]` Can you explain ?

Comment: @jossefaz when Pydantic does the first pass on the schema, it assumes the type is a list. In that case I override the schema to remove that as an option, because we want it just to be a basic string type